# Count how many Months in a column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

If I have excel listing as such...
Each on its own cell

```
A1.   1/25/18
A2.   1/30/18
A3.   2/05/18
A4.   2/15/18
A5.   2/16/18
```

How can I determine

- January has 2 listings
- And February has 3

I tried:

```
=COUNTIFS(A1:A5,MONTH(A1))
```

to get 2 for Jan count

Comment: `=COUNTIFS(A1:A5,MONTH(A1))` so what did that return? Please [edit] and update your question.

Comment: Didn’t work It gave me a 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `=COUNTIFS(A1:A5,MONTH(A1))`

That formula gets month part only for A1, you need to get it for all the values.

Unfortunately you can't convert the range within `COUNTIFS`, you need to use another function.

It'll be `SUM` within an [array formula](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7):
`=SUM(IF(MONTH($A$1:$A$5)=C1,1,0))`
As it's an array formula you need to press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER instead of ENTER after typing it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

So you tried:

```
=COUNTIFS(A1:A5,MONTH(A1))
```

This will not work because you have the condition to count if anything in column A is equal to 1 essentially. 1/25/18 is not equal to 2 and same for the rest.

There are two ways you can accomplish what you want. You can either use an assist column or do it all in one formula. I would actually recommend the assist column though.

**Using assist column**

So since all of your data is in column A, in column B1 put:

```
=Month(A1)
```

and then drag down. In column B1 put:

```
=countif(B:B,1)
```

That way your data is of the same format. =Month() will always return a number so that helps you compare a list of numbers with the one you are looking for instead of looking in dates for a number like you had before.

**Doing it all in one formula**

The other way is to use an array formula. Do keep in mind that in general array formulas are extremely slow and CPU intensive so should be used sparingly.

In cell B1 you would put:

```
{=SUM(IF(MONTH(A1:A5)=1,1,0))}
```

After entering this formula make sure you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> so it recognizes that there is an array.

Month() in this formula returns a list of numbers (an array) and then the IF() statement says that if any of those numbers = 1 then return 1 and if not then return 0 (which is essentially counting). On the outside of the IF, the SUM simply adds up all of those returned values.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

*In Cell B2 write this Formula to get count of Months:*

```
=SUMPRODUCT(1*(MONTH($A$2:$A$6)=MONTH(A2)))
```

*In C2 write this Array Formula to generate unique list of Month's count:*

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$6, MATCH(0,COUNTIF($C$1:C1, $A$2:$A$6), 0)),"")}
```

**N.B.** Finish this formula with Ctrl + Shift + Enter .

Comment: there are already two answers to this question, both providing simpler formulas than your answer. If you post another answer please make sure it actually provides new information, and if you post complex formulas please make sure you explain how they work.